# How can I turn a number ( in seconds) to time format?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

How can I turn a number ( in seconds) to time format ? Also, no army time, just 12 hour format.

I guess since the start of the day, im not to sure how to elaborate really. I want to create an action that will calculate how much time an event will take and create a schedule, The length of time is based on amount of people in the event. Ive figured that part out to get an integer in seconds, I just need to translate that into an actual time.

Comment: I think you're going to be more specific.  Seconds since what?  The start of the day?  Unix Epoch?

Comment: I guess since the start of the day, im not to sure how to elaborate really. I want to create an action that will calculate how much time an event will take and create a schedule, The length of time is based on amount of people in the event. Ive figured that part out to get an integer in seconds, I just need to translate that into an actual time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in [divmod](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#divmod) is useful for this.  For example **11 hours 10 minutes and 9 seconds** is equal to 40209 total seconds.

```
>>> total_seconds = 40209
>>> minutes, seconds = divmod(total_seconds, 60)
>>> hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)
>>> print '{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(hours, minutes, seconds)
11:10:09
```

Comment: almost, except after it passes 12:00, it goes on to 13:00 and just continues up, any ideas of how I can fix that?

Comment: What do you want it to look like?

Comment: from 12:00 am to 1:00pm and 12:00 pm to 1:00am, instead of 12:00 to 13:00

Comment: just do another divmod on the hours, with remainder 12 instead of 60 this time